# Odd behavior using f-string hex number formatting?

Tags: python-3.x, f-string

I need to print out two hex numbers with leading zeros.
My original code did something like this:

```
"<0x%08x 0x%08x>" % (x, y)
```

I am trying to replace this with an f-string with:

```
f"<{x:#08x} {y:#08x}>"
```

but when I use '#' there are no leading zeros.

```
# will insert 0x
0 should add leading zeroes
8 should make it 8 digits after the leading 0x
x will use lower-case hex
```

So it looks like '#' and specifying the width are incompatible with one another?

I was expecting something like:

```
x=0x600000
y=0x200000
print("<{x:#08x} {y:#08x}>")
```

would display:

```
<0x00600000 0x00200000>
```

but the actual result is:

```
<0x600000 0x200000>
```

Comment: The true equivalent to your original format string would be `f"<0x{x:08x} 0x{y:08x}>"`, with the `0x` not involved in the formatting at all [TIO.run](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8LWoMLMAAS4KoFMIwizoCgzr0QjTcnGoKK6wsrAoqJWAciqBLPslDT//wcA)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the `0x` characters are part of the `width`. Therefore add 2 to the width specifier. Exampe:

```
x=0x600000
y=0x200000
print(f"<{x:#010x} {y:#08x}>")

<0x00600000 0x200000>
```